# MongoDB query: filter and exclude fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

I have the following data structure:

```
{
"groups" : [ 
    {
        "internalName" : "Group1",
        "fields" : [ 
            {
                "internalName" : "Field1",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "isShow" : true
                }
            }, 
            {
                "internalName" : "Field2",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "isHide" : false
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "internalName" : "Group2",
        "fields" : [ 
            {
                "internalName" : "Field1",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "IsHide" : false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"internalName" : "Layout1"
},
{
"groups" : [ 
    {
        "internalName" : "Group3",
        "fields" : [ 
            {
                "internalName" : "Field2",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "isShow" : true
                }
            }, 
            {
                "internalName" : "Field4",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "isHide" : false
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "internalName" : "Group4",
        "fields" : [ 
            {
                "internalName" : "Field3",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "IsHide" : false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"internalName" : "Layout2"
}
```

The goal is filter this data by fields internal names and return only needed data - only groups which contain only fields with selected internal names. For example with data above:
Filtered internal names - "Field2", "Field4"
Expected data to return:

```
{
"internalName" : "Layout1",
"groups" : [ 
    {
        "internalName" : "Group1",
        "fields" : [  
            {
                "internalName" : "Field2",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "isHide" : false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
},
{
"internalName" : "Layout2",
"groups" : [ 
    {
        "internalName" : "Group3",
        "fields" : [ 
            {
                "internalName" : "Field4",
                "uiProperties" : {
                    "isHide" : false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I'm try something like that

```
{
        $match: {  
            "groups.fields.internalName": {
                $in: ["Field2", "Field4"]
            }
        }
   },
   {
        $unwind: "$groups"
   },
   {  
        $unwind: "$groups.fields"
   },
   {  
        $group: {  
            _id:"$_id",
            internalName: {
                 $first: "$internalName",
            },    
            groups:{  
                 $push: {
                      internalName: "$groups.internalName",
                      fields: "$groups.fields"
                 }   
            }
        }
    }
```

But it's not worked well..
Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your aggregation pipeline.. First unwind the group elements and then the fields element

```
{
  {$unwind: "$groups"},
  {$unwind: "$groups.fields"},
  {$match: {"groups.fields.internalName", {$eq: {$or: ["Field2", "Field4",...]}}}},

}
```

Later group it the way you have done it.